# How to get extension to return subclass type

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to extend `NSManagedObject` to get an object but as part of a child context. I'm trying to get the function to return the subclass type - not a ManagedObject.

```
extension NSManagedObject {

func inContext(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self {
    let objectID = self.objectID
    let childObject = context.object(with: objectID)
    return childObject
}
```

Any idea how I can get the function to return the correct type?

Comment: Did you mean that you want to fitch an object from coreData ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to make this generic!

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    func inContext<T: NSManagedObject>(_ context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> T? {
        let objectID = self.objectID
        let childObject = context.object(with: objectID)
        return childObject as? T
    }
}
```

Unfortunately you have to call it like this, with a type annotation, unless the type can be inferred.

```
let objectInContext: MyManagedobjectType? = myManagedObject.inContext(someContext, type: MyManagedObjectType.self)
```

Comment: Great - thanks very much!